# Designing baseboard for Intel processor

Tags: pcb, fpga, cpu, pinout, intel

We are studying the feasibility of designing a minimal board for a high end CPU such as Intel's 8th Gen Core i7/9 alongside some FPGA. We  have experience with DDR3/PCIe designs and know about high frequency PCB designs.

We don't have the intention to write its software, and shall stick to general bootloader/OS unless some initial state BIOS/bootloader is needed.

For such processors, are all of the design documents openly available?

On their website, I've seen some family specifications/datasheets and other design documents, but they don't seems to cover everything needed, for example I've searched for a while on Intel website and not been able to find packages layout, pinout, timings and any design examples/layout. I've seen some minimal images of pinout but not as an official reference.

Comment: I'm guessing you will need an Intel Developer Premier account to access all necessary documentation.

Comment: You should ask Intel for this documentation. But I imagine they will give it only to authorized mainboard manufacturers. Without such kind of documentation I think, that this generation of processor will long be end of life before you figure it all out.

Comment: @tobalt I'll note that custom server boards do exist, so clearly Intel is willing to allow companies to sign up and get this info, the only question is whether it's too expensive or comes with onerous requirements

Comment: This might be easier to achieve with AMD Ryzen CPUs: They don't need a chipset. AMD has a chip called the "Knoll activator" that puts a Ryzen CPU into a SoC mode so it boots using its own integrated I/O.

Comment: Yeah it seems the i386 days are gone, company’s change. While ounce they made computers affordable, and seemed to welcome folks toward learning and technology. I applied for an nda and considered encorperating but I was denied. They were nice and welcomed me to return with questions however I couldn’t help feel it was a joke. Maybe poor confidence or maybe that’s how the pc startup world works or just a billion dollar national industry perhaps more operated by trusts and heavily proprietary business practices. But it’s not just geeks, it’s a business too. So who knows.

Comment: What it was told was that what I wanted to do was not the direction or intent of the intel components. Even then around 2016 they were looking to I guess the fpga industry and other things and phasing out the intel atoms. So it could had been just that.

Comment: Also too they do own basically an monopoly on the x86-64 market with AMD being the only competitor (who has turned commonly to federal/state funded means often to compete).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, and this is something you probably also experienced working with DDR3 designs, manufacturers of cutting edge integrated devices want to know what you are building, how you plan to use it, and how many units you plan to sell. If it is academic, which institution is backing you. They do this to make it more difficult for competitors to review their features and implementation, to collect market data to plan their next products, but also often because of exclusivity , national security, and other potential legal and market requirements that necessitate signing agreements or other paperwork before allowing you to see their IP..

Personally I think it's a heavy approach just to see datasheets, and many manufacturers are seeing the value of open documentation and more "self service" sales channel, but not all manufacturers will be on board,  that is the nature of the current device and integration market.

Your best bet is to get in contact with the manufacturer (Intel) via your regional sales channel, explain your application,  and hope they will provide you an offer for discounted or free documentation.

Alternatively gray (unauthorized) or black (stolen) design materials can probably be found  if one looks.